# Trying to translate weighted RNG function from php to python 3 but am confused

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

Please don't think badly of me for asking, but I really am confused.

```
    <?php
      function getRandomWeightedElement(array $weightedValues) {
        $rand = mt_rand(1, (int) array_sum($weightedValues));

        foreach ($weightedValues as $key => $value) {
          $rand -= $value;
          if ($rand <= 0) {
            return $key;
          }
        }
      }
    ?>
```

I am trying to translate this function I've used for a long time into Python 3, but don't understand why my Python version sometimes returns more than one key from test1.

```
    #getRandomWeightedElement
    #Takes in a keyed dictionary and returns a random element
    import random

    def getRandomWeightedElement(**data):
        rand = random.randint(1, sum(data.values()))

        for key, value in data.items():
            rand -= value
            if rand <= 0:
                print(key)

    test1 = {'One':25,'Two':25,'Three':25,'Four':25}

    getRandomWeightedElement(**test1)
```

So basically I'm asking, why doesn't my function in Python 3 work the same as the function in Php and why does it return multiple keys from test1?

I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious, I've just started Python and don't yet know how everything operates. Any help I would greatly appreciate. Please also let me know if I've asked my question incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original PHP code, your function returns the key as soon as `rand` becomes a non-positive number, but in your Python code, you simply print the key without returning.

You should return the key in your new code also, and print the returning value of the function instead:

```
import random

def getRandomWeightedElement(**data):
    rand = random.randint(1, sum(data.values()))

    for key, value in data.items():
        rand -= value
        if rand <= 0:
            return key

test1 = {'One': 25, 'Two': 25, 'Three': 25, 'Four': 25}

print(getRandomWeightedElement(**test1))
```

Comment: Thank you, I had a return before the print initially, but it didn't display anything. I now see why and that I was being stupid